# How to install gcc on macOS such that `gcc --version` reports "InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin"

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

This question pertains to [ImportError on `import pycurl` (Python 3.10, macOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70079520/importerror-on-import-pycurl-python-3-10-macos)

I'm hitting errors with installing `pycurl` on macOS, and I'm trying to use information in this gist comment: https://gist.github.com/vidakDK/de86d751751b355ed3b26d69ecdbdb99#gistcomment-3971684

The hint is that it succeeds on a machine reporting an InstalledDir of  `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin` but fails on a machine reporting an InstalledDir of `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`

And this pattern-matches with my setup:

```
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

So if I can figure out how to achieve a `gcc` that reports "InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin" I am one step closer to a solution.

`brew install gcc` gives:

```
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/avr-gcc@8/8.4.0_2: 1,741 files, 204.7MB
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/avr-gcc@8/8.4.0_1... (1,741 files, 205.0MB)
```

... and I'm not sure what's going on with `gcc` vs `avr-gcc`.

Before and after the `brew install gcc`, `find / -name gcc -type f 2>/dev/null` reports the same locations:

```
> find / -name gcc -type f 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/gcc
/usr/share/file/magic/gcc
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/gcc
/System/Volumes/Update/mnt1/usr/bin/gcc
/System/Volumes/Update/mnt1/usr/share/file/magic/gcc
/System/Volumes/Data/usr/share/file/magic/gcc
/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/gcc
/System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Xcode10.3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
/System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
/Applications/Xcode10.3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
```

And `/path/to/gcc --version` before and after on each reports `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`

How to achieve the desired `gcc` `InstalledDir` path? There must be another way of installing `gcc` for macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```